# Variable dans appel jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Little worries: I use the jQuery barcode 2.0.3 plugin. I am looking to do a function that has each call creates a barcode.

Here is my code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/sample/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/jquery-barcode.js"></script>
<script>
  function code_barre(ref, n) {
    var refcode = ref;
    $('#bcTarget' + n.id).barcode(refcode, "code93", {
      barWidth: 2,
      barHeight: 40,
      fontSize: 24
    });
    value = "code93"
  }
</script>

<?php
   ////////////////////////////////// Connection à la base ///////////////////////
   include '../0/bdd_connection.php';
  ?>
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php
   $cont=0;
      $reponse = $bdd->prepare('SELECT catalogue_ref, cat_ref, cat_ref_unit FROM catalogue as ca
       INNER JOIN catalogue_stock as cs on ca.catalogue_ref=cs.cat_ref
            WHERE catalogue_ref = ? ');
            $reponse ->execute(array('REAC-0001'));
            while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
             {
              $cont++;
              echo $donnees['cat_ref'].'-'.$donnees['cat_ref_unit'].' ';
              echo '<script>code_barre(\''.$donnees['cat_ref'].'-'.$donnees['cat_ref_unit'].'\',\''.$cont.'\')</script>';
              echo '<div id="bcTarget'.$cont.'" name="bcTarget'.$cont.'"></div>';
              
             }
            $reponse->closeCursor();

        ?>
```

Comment: Everything works except creating barcodes ... If I type the id it works ... but $ ('# bcTarget' + n.id) does not work

Comment: It should be `$('#bcTarget'+ n)` not `$('#bcTarget'+ n.id)` because `n` is a number.

Comment: I have already tried unfortunately it does not work either

Comment: $('#bcTarget1'), $('#bcTarget2') etc work perfectly, but as soon as I put a variable nothing ...

Comment: Can you `console.log` those values and see if they are the right ones? Put `console.log(ref, n);` as the first statement in `code_barre`, what do you see in the console?

Comment: too strong ... I'm too tired ... well played my friend ... thank you very much

Comment: @julus is it  working now?

Answer (score 0):

In the function `code_bar`, `$('#bcTarget' + n.id)` should be `$('#bcTarget' + n)` as `n` is already a number.

In the php code, the element should be appended before the script as the script relies on the element being in the DOM when it executes:

```
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()) {
    $cont++;
    echo $donnees['cat_ref'].'-'.$donnees['cat_ref_unit'].' ';

    echo '<div id="bcTarget'.$cont.'" name="bcTarget'.$cont.'"></div>';  // <=== put this first

    echo '<script>code_barre(\''.$donnees['cat_ref'].'-'.$donnees['cat_ref_unit'].'\',\''.$cont.'\')</script>';
}
```